# why is one division inside the other though their code indicate the opposite?

Tags: html, css

My second divisions is inside the first though my code indicates that they should be separate divisions. Can someone explain this? and how to modify the code so that I can have separate divisions? (that is all the detail I got)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning CSS</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .large{
        font-size: 300%;
    }

    #blue{
        color: blue;
    }

    .green{
        color: green;
    }

    .underline{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }

    .bold{
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .blackbox{
        background-color:black;
        color: white;
        font-style: italic;
        width: 400px;
        position: relative;


    }

    .redbox{
        background-color:red;
        width: 400px;

    }
    .greenbox{
        background-color:#1AEB4F;
        width: 400px;
    }

    .clear{
        clear: both;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="redbox">
        <img src = "image/sheep.jpg" width = 300px />
        <div class = "clear" />
        <p class = "greenbox">SHEEP</p>
    </div>

    <div class = "blackbox">
        <img src = "image/girl.jpg" width = 300px/>
        <div class = "clear" />
        <p class = "greenbox">GIRL</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AFAIK the `div` element is not self-closing. Also AFAIK you need to add quotation marks around the `width` values of your images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out, the divs are not self closing, the page is rendering as follows:

```
<div class="redbox">
    <img src="image/sheep.jpg" width="300px">
    <div class="clear">
        <p class="greenbox">SHEEP</p>
    </div>

    <div class="blackbox">
        <img src="image/girl.jpg" width="300px">
        <div class="clear">
            <p class="greenbox">GIRL</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to fix this, if you want the clear div to end right there, you can end the div on the same line like this:

```
<div class="redbox">
    <img src="image/sheep.jpg" width="300px">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="greenbox">SHEEP</p>
</div>

<div class="blackbox">
    <img src="image/girl.jpg" width="300px">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="greenbox">GIRL</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<body>
    <div class="redbox">
        <img src = "image/sheep.jpg" width = 300px />
        <div class = "clear" ></div>
        <p class = "greenbox">SHEEP</p>
    </div>

    <div class = "blackbox">
        <img src = "image/girl.jpg" width = 300px/>
        <div class = "clear" ></div>
        <p class = "greenbox">GIRL</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can only use `<element attributes/>` to close certain element types.